# Is there a term for "rational functions" with non-integer powers $\frac{n_1x^{p_1/q_1} + \dots}{D(x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

If rational functions are functions whose value is defined by an equation of the form:
$$
 f(x) = \frac{N(x)}{D(x)},
$$
where $N(x)$ and $D(x)$ are polynomials and $D(x) \neq 0$, is there a term for functions defined by an equation such as:
$$
g(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}-a}{D(x)}, 
$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $D(x)$ may be a polynomial or may also have rational powers?

Comment: I would have thought you would have a rational function of an $n$th root of $x$, where $n$ was a common multiple of the denominators of the exponents.

Comment: Right -- "rational in $\sqrt[n]{x}$," that does make sense. Thanks for weighing-in!